# Why don't my cells show up?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sidebar

I am learning to write code without a storyboard and I decided to add Side Bar to my project. I used ENSwiftSideMenu library and the examples that they have provided uses storyboard.

I tried to write it without and it shows a side bar but I have a problem. My sidebar is actually a tableviewController and it should have 2 cells but when I open up my side bar it doesn't show me my cells. But it prints to log that it adds those cells. (I added print methods).

So how can I make my cells visible if that's possible?

```
import UIKit

class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var arr = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)
        arr.append("Lesson 1")
        arr.append("Lesson 2")

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) ->    Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arr.count 
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("I am calling you")
        let cell = MyTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        //let cell = UITableViewCell(
        cell.textLabel!.text = self.arr[indexPath.row]
        print(self.arr[indexPath.row])

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
    }

    import UIKit
    import ENSwiftSideMenu
    import Cartography

    class SideNavigationViewController: ENSideMenuNavigationController {

    init(){
      // super.init(coder: NSCode)

        super.init(menuViewController: TempViewController(), contentViewController: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var menu = MenuTableViewController()
        menu.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 180)
        sideMenu = ENSideMenu(sourceView: self.view, menuViewController: menu, menuPosition: ENSideMenuPosition.Left)
        sideMenu!.menuWidth = 180
        view.bringSubviewToFront(navigationBar)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct reuseIdentifier?

Comment: Did you set the delegate?

Comment: Try reload your tableview after appending data to `arr`